# MJPEGStream Display Stream Aforge.Video.dll

Tags: windows, vb.net, ip-camera, aforge

I'm trying to stream an IPCAM D'Link using the Aforge Libraries but i'm not succeed:
I want to display the video stream into an PB control.
My Code:

```
Imports AForge.Video 
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Try
            Dim stream As New MJPEGStream("http://190.6.198.3/video/mjpg.cgi")
            stream.Login() = "admin"
            stream.Password() = ""
            stream.Start()
        Catch ex As System.Net.WebException
            MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 1):

you kinda mixing the MJPEGStream and the control

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim mjpegSource As New MJPEGStream("rtsp://192.0.0.64:554/cam[CHANNEL]/mjpeg")
        mjpegSource.Login = "admin"
        mjpegSource.Password = ""
    VideoSourcePlayer1.VideoSource = mjpegSource
```

**error** is the url prefix is not recognized
this is how i fixed
but with `vlc` can streaming