# Aforge Live Stream From IP Camera HttpWebRequest

Tags: c#, aforge, ip-camera

I am using Aforge to try to get a live stream from an IP Camera.  My problem is, my connection keeps getting closed for some reason.  For testing purposes, I have the camera connected directly to my computer and am connecting to it through this LAN.

The error:

> The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed
>   unexpectedly.

Here is the code I'm using:

```
stream.NewFrame += new NewFrameEventHandler(video_NewFrame);
stream.VideoSourceError += new VideoSourceErrorEventHandler(stream_VideoSourceError);
stream.Login = "login";
stream.Password = "pass";
stream.RequestTimeout = 10000;
stream.Source = "http://192.168.0.33/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=320x240&Quality=Standard";  
stream.Start();
```

I have saw where some people have recommended putting a setting in app.config, and I have done that as well:

```
<system.net>
  <settings>
    <httpWebRequest useUnsafeHeaderParsing="true"/>
  </settings>
</system.net>
```

Without the edit off app.config, I get a different error. (Protocol violation)

Has anyone ran across these issues or know how to get it working?

**Note:** I also tried getting data without Aforge [like this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15537/Camera-Vision-video-surveillance-on-C) but it resulted in the same error.

Comment: Try opening it in VLC and see if it works there.  I find VLC is great for testing out MJPEG connections when I'm not sure if my code is working right.

Comment: may be related to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10823848/mjpegstream-display-stream-aforge-video-dll (though not enough detail on other question to know for sure)

Comment: @Peter yes, looks related.  No info there though

Comment: Did you try using VLC, or even just pointing your webbrowser at the URL?  Almost every browser, except for IE, supports MJPEG streams natively.

Comment: @Peter I tried using VLC, but couldn't get it to work on there.  When I point browser to the camera's ip, I'm prompted for a username/pass, then the streaming starts.  In my application, I use the stated URL.  I also used the stated URL in my browser, and it asks me to open or save the file. (tells me its an octet-stream).  So I believe the connection is not the problem...I don't know..

Comment: Any updates there? Could u make it working?

Comment: @Peretz I got a different camera (Axis) and it works as expected now.  I'm sure it had something to do with the outdated camera

Answer (score 2):

try the following to see if it works.

```
stream.Login = "login";
stream.Password = "pass";
stream.ForceBasicAuthentication = true;
stream.RequestTimeout = 10000;
stream.Source = "http://192.168.0.33/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=320x240&Quality=Standard";  
stream.Start();
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe it's an option in aforge ( https://code.google.com/p/aforge/source/browse/trunk/Sources/Video/MJPEGStream.cs), but it looks like the camera expects HTTP v1.0.  See the manual, http://csj.psn-web.net/netwkcam_net/download/us/document/NEW_Camera_CGI_Interface_v4.30.pdf, on page 56.

> (1) Start reception Establish a connection (open the socket), and send
>   the following command string to HTTP port. "GET
>   http:// xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:yy/nphMotionJpeg?Resolution=320x240&Quality=Standard
>   **HTTP/1.0\r\n**" xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx: IP address or domain name yy: HTTP port
>   no. (Not required if the port number is set to 80)

If you do have access to the code you could try

```
//setting http v1.0 in c#
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)base.GetWebRequest(address);
request.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
```

Also, try enabling guest access and removing your username/password from your code and see if that works.

Comment: Tried this, still same problems.  Good info though.